# win32api open external program and do stuff

Tags: python

I am running python 2.7 on Windows and I would like to open an external program (lets say notepad.exe) and type something and save that file. I guess I have to use `win32api` but I dont know how to tell python what he has to do within notepad.exe

```
win32api.WinExec('notepad.exe')
```

This command opens notepad but I don't know how to paste text to it and go to "File" -> "Save As..." and save the file. Is that even possible?

Actually I wanted to do that with a program similar to Paint (which is not available as a command line tool), that opens data files and saves them as .jpg files. So the only thing I have to do is tell python where the "File" button(s...) are and to execute them... Is this possible with python? The only (ugly) solution I have is using coordinates and simulate mouse clicks / keypresses, but that is really ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad does not (to the best of my knowledge) offer a COM interface. This will defeat your attempts at automation.  If you are trying to do notepad.exe automation, you will need to look at some sort of Windows automation system. I like AutoIT -- http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way to simulate some activities in a non COM/DCOM application is to go through the keyboard stimulation.
One simple exemple switch from the python command to the last ran application (notepad.exe for instance) and execute ALT+F which open the file menu: the win32api can also simulate mouse mouvement drag & drop and so on.

```
import win32api,win32con,time
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_TAB, 0, 0, 0)
time.sleep(0.1)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_TAB, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_MENU, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
time.sleep(0.1)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(ord('F'), 0, 0, 0)
win21api.keybd_event(ord('F'), 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_MENU, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

as you can see sometime .. a little delay is required to let the event enabling changing the windows focus.